# create a mock class for callout in managed package

Tags: apex, unit-test, callout, failing-tests, httpcalloutmock

we have a managed package and the function **call_out** is making a http request.
In the package we can use this code to create a test for it:

```
    Test.startTest();
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Mock());
    call_out(curid);
    Test.stopTest();
```

however when we installed this package in another org, we want to use this function again, however in test, it fails.

```
    Test.startTest();
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new package.Mock());
    package.call_out(curid);
    Test.stopTest();
```

it gives us this error: `Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts`

what is wrong? and whether it is possible to test it in target org? 
is going around it using Test.isRunningTest() the only possible way?

Comment: Take a look at this one: [Managed package callout invoked from managed package extension causing test class failure](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18212/2995)

Comment: I'll close it out as a duplicate then. Glad it helped. Cheers!